# Equivalent of cd for scp in vim

Tags: vim

When using the delightful `netrw` support in vim to open a file, opening directly works well, as in

```
:e scp://hostname//path/to/file
```

however, you can't change the working directory via

```
:cd scp://hostname//path/
```

Is there a way of getting this or equivalent behavior? Key part is I want to be able to use a relative path to edit files.

Please feel free to use scripts or plugins in your answer.

Comment: what's up with the closes? I thought we'd well established that only us programmers use vim. this question may very well involve scripting in its answer too!

Comment: don't worry, from time to time people vote to close on Vim questions. If closed, we'll reopen it. And for reference, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25925/160504) is the link to the Vim discussion on meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of current directory is a property of a process. Since your vim process and the process at the other end of the scp are different, there is no way to effect its notion of the current directory. That said,

- scp likely starts with a current working directory of the user's home directory. Things like `scp user@host:txt/foo.txt .` usually do the right thing.
- Set a vim or environment variable to `scp://hostname//path/` and then use `:e $var/file`. Details how to do this left as an exercise :-)
- Folks on usenet newsgroups like `comp.editors` know all about vim.